# CrashPlan setup

Tags: backup

I finally decided to make a proper backup setup for my home computers.
I have 2 laptops, mine and my wife's, both PC and two desktops one (PC) for multimedia purposes and one (Ubuntu Linux) for local backup.

So currently i am using Crashplan to backup everything to the Linux server and all looks fine and dandy but i decided to back up my server to the web with CrashPlan Central. I have no problems with backing up random stuff on server, but when i want to backup those encrypted files that are the backups from other comuters made by Crashplan i get a probelm.

I installed Crashplan with default locations and my backups are stored in `/usr/local/crashplan/backupArchives` folder.  When i check it for online backup it doesn't backup anything.

Am i doing something wrong or it is not possible to upload the files created by other Crashplan clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not backup CrashPlan Backup Archives at CrashPlan Central.

I think they do this to prevent customers to buy a licence for one machine to backup multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

There are hard coded exclusions in CrashPlan preventing it from backing up CrashPlan files:
http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/articles/admin_excludes

You cannot change that excludes, but I suggest a look at this
hard coded exclusions to avoid surprises.